# Reading an array in EV3 Mindstorm

Tags: lego-mindstorms

I am working with my daughter on Lego's EV3 programing language. I am trying to read an array and output it to the display grid, but it isn't working.

Two questions:
 1: How do I solve this problem?
 2: Is there a better way to error check on this language?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The read block I created with a new variable name, and that doesn't work. It is now working.